# How do you make an intro screen for a game

Tags: javascript, html, css

https://github.com/Mzema4818/Dragon-Escape/blob/master/index.html

Here is my github index for my game, What I am looking for is a intro screen when you open the game up, where it asks you if you want to play or look at the rules

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You call start game immediately when the page loads:

```
<body onload="startGame()">
```

Instead of having the game start immediately, you should probably create a method called `init` that shows the different controls on your canvas/html that asks the user to play or to look at the rules.

If the user, chooses play then you should call `startGame()`